# Make an element with position: absolute stick out of the screen without provoking horizontal owerflow

Tags: html, css, position, overflow

I have a circle for decoration

```
<div class="circle">
    <img src="noun-dashed-circle-orange.svg" alt="">
</div>
```

```
.circle {
    width: 185px;
    height: 185px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1430px;
    right: -96px;
}
```

When the circle is sticking out of the screen I have overflow-x which i don't need (the horizontal scrool).

**Also I don't want overflow-x: hidden;**

The circle is directly inside `<body></body>`

[image of circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJT1I.png)

Comment: use it as background instead

Comment: @TemaniAfif What do I need to use as background?

Comment: Use that image as background to the div rather than have the img element.

Comment: @AHaworth This img element is spinning, it has an animation and cannot be a part of the big background

Comment: Please put a runnable snippet into your question which shows the problem. Transforms like rotation may alter what is suitable so please include that. And run the snippet yourself to ensure it demonstrates what is wrong. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score -1):

for "Make an element with position: absolute stick out of the screen without provoking horizontal owerflow" you should be add:

```css
.container {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      overflow-x: hidden; /* Hide horizontal overflow */
}

.circle {
      width: 185px;
      height: 185px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 1430px;
      right: -96px;
      margin-right: -96px; /* Compensate for right positioning */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="circle">
        <img src="noun-dashed-circle-orange.svg" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: AI generated content is [currently banned](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/20153035) on Stack Overflow. Please read the [AI Policy](/help/ai-policy) for more information.

Comment: just the paragraph not the code

Comment: "any answer crafted **in part** or in whole" - [AI Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy)